# On the $R$ module $R/I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a (not necessarily commutative) ring with $1_R$ and $I\subseteq R$ its *left* ideal. Since $I$ is a normal (additive) subgroup of $R$, we can define the quotient group 
$$R/I:=\{r+I:\ r\in R\}.$$
Also, we can define the scalar multiplication
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\cdot: R\times (R/I) & \longrightarrow (R/I),\\
(r,s+I)& \longmapsto r \cdot(s+I):= rs+I.
\end{alignat*}

So, $(R/I,+)$ under with this scalar multiplication is a left $R-$module.

However, $R/I$ is *not* always a ring, because $I$ is not a 2-sided ideal of $R$, so we can *not* define the quotient ring.

***Are all the claims above correct? And could you please give some examples for this factor module?***

*Thanks.*

Comment: Usually the quotient ring is formed with a two-sided ideal, not just a left ideal, but this seems correct to me.

Comment: @jcqell Thank you for your comment. I know, that's why I asked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> could you please give some examples for this factor module?

In $R=M_2(F)$, for any field $F$, the subset of matrices whose right column is zeros forms a left ideal that is not a right ideal, and you can compute the quotient. If you like you can even use the field of two elements so that it is very small.

The quotient is a left $R$ module, but not a ring.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.